# CSS animate on position change from absolute to relative

Tags: html, css, hover, css-animations

I have a `div` with `position: relative`, on hover I want to move the `div`, achieving this with `position: absolute` with animation, and then I want to go back to its original position with an animation again. I managed to animate when the mouse enters the `div`, but not when it exits. Can you please help?

Code:

```
.team-member {
   &.hovered {
      .name-container {
         top: 30%;
         position: absolute;
         transition: top 0.7s ease-in-out;
      }
   }
   .name-container {
      transition: top 0.7s ease-in-out;
      transition: position 0.7s ease-in-out;
      top: 90%; // Just so the animation can be seen
      position: relative;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that are confusing in your questions, more specifically:

- why do you have a `.hovered` class? It seems you are applying a class in some ways (maybe via javascript?), but you don't really need it, because you can rely on the `:hover` pseudo-class.
- why changing the position during an animation? It can make the development more complex, because you potentially change the reference system only for a few seconds. The transition should be sufficient to move the element temporarily!

That said, perhaps you want to use the `:not(:active)` pseudo-class to control the animation when the element goes back in position, the following example should help you in achieving what you are looking for:

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
}

.content:hover {
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out; /* controls the animation when going forward */
  translate: 40px;
}

.content:not(:active) {
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out; /* controls the animation when going back */
}

/* Visual helpers, just for the demo: */
.content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="content"> 
      content 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

To achieve the desired effect of animating the movement of the div both on hover and when the mouse leaves, you need to apply the transition properties to both the base state and the hovered state. Here's how you can modify your CSS:

```css
.team-member {
    .name-container {
        transition: top 0.7s ease-in-out, position 0.7s ease-in-out;
        top: 90%; // Just so the animation can be seen
        position: relative;
    }

    &:hover {
        .name-container {
            top: 30%;
            position: absolute;
        }
    }
}
```

With this modification, the transition properties are applied to .name-container in its base state as well as in its hovered state. This should produce the desired animation effect both when hovering over the div and when the mouse leaves.`

Comment: Well the thing is that I want to be position: relative, when it is not hovered

Comment: then you may try this : 

.team-member {
    .name-container {
        transition: top 0.7s ease-in-out, position 0.7s ease-in-out;
        top: 90%; // Just so the animation can be seen
        position: relative;
    }

    &:hover {
        .name-container {
            top: 30%;
            position: absolute;
            transition: top 0.7s ease-in-out; /* Transition only the top property on hover */
        }
    }
}